# Why this code keeps crashing

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Why this code gives error:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    char x='\0',i=0;
    vector<char> text;
    do
    {
        cout<< "Enter a char" << endl;
        cin>>x;
        if(x<65||(x>90&&x<97)||x>123)
        {
            cout<<"Out of Range-Please Enter Letters"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
    text.push_back(x);  
    if(x=='n'||x=='N'){
            text.clear();
            cout<<"Vector Cleared"<<endl;
            continue;
                       }    
    cout<<text.size()<<endl;
    cout<<"Vector now holds\n";
    for(i=0;i< signed (text.size() ) ;i++)
        {
        cout<< text[i] << endl;
        }
    }while(x!='y');

    cout << "Vector size is " << text.size() << " Vector Capacity is " << text.capacity() << endl;
    vector<char>::iterator it = text.begin();
    for (; it != text.end() ; it++)
        cout << *it << endl;
    cout << "Enter Position to delete: " << endl;

    cin >> i;
    text.erase(text.begin() + i - 1);
    it = text.begin() ;
    for (; it != text.end() ; it++)
        cout << *it << endl;


}
```

Debug assertion failure, expression vector iterator + offset out of range.

Comment: what's the input? Have you set breakpoints and stepped through your program?

Comment: text.erase(text.begin() + i - 1);
should fail if i > text.size() or i < 1, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: At what line does the program crash? I can see it happening with the text.erase if you input 0 for i, then you try to erase the position before text.begin().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will crash because `i` is a character, therefore `cin` will read a character. For example if someone enters a value `8`, the value of `i` will be 38 (if you platform is using ASCII encoding).

Plus testing characters for their values is very bad practice use `isalpha()` from `cctype` header instead.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is you are using `char` as an array index:

`cout<< text[i] << endl;`

You also should consider prefix (not postfix) operators for non-primitive types to improve your performance at these lines:

`for (; it != text.end() ; it++)`

and

`for (; it != text.end() ; it++)`

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Use `std::string` instead of
   `std::vector<char>`.
2. Use character constants instead of
   their ASCII decimal number ('A'
   instead of 65).
3. Prefer library functions instead of
   comparing character ranges (see
   `isprint, isdigit, isalpha,` etc.)
4. Convert text and characters to upper
   or lower case before comparing.  Use
   `tolower` or `toupper`.
5. Prefer one variable declaration per
   line.
6. Add spaces around operators,
   improves readability.

I converted your example to use `std::string`, character functions and added space around operators.  Compare to your style for simplicity and ease of reading:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    char x='\0';
    unsigned int i=0;
    string text;
    do
    {
        cout<< "Enter a char" << endl;
        cin>>x;
//        if(x<65||(x>90&&x<97)||x>123)
        if (! isprint(x))
        {
            cout<<"Out of Range-Please Enter Letters"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        text += x;  
        if(toupper(x) == 'N')
        {
            text.clear();
            cout<<"String Cleared"<<endl;
            continue;
        }    
        cout << text.length() << endl;
        cout<<"String now holds\n";
        cout << text << endl;
    }while(tolower(x) != 'y');

    cout << "String length is: " << text.length() << ", capacity: " << text.capacity() << endl;
    cout << text << endl;
    cout << "Enter Position to delete: " << endl;

    cin >> i;
    text.erase(text.begin() + i - 1);
    cout << "After erase: " << text << endl;
    return 0;
}
```